# RDLC file DataSet and Overlapping error messages

Tags: asp.net, dataset, datasource, rdlc

I am working on RDLC reports in asp.net.
I had one datasource for my report. It was working perfectly.
But now I changed it and assigned another datasource to it as well.
here is the code:

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rptAdmissionNote" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" 
        Font-Size="8pt" Height="100%" Width="100%" 
        InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" 
        WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
        <LocalReport ReportPath="Reports\Admission\rptAdmissionNoteReport.rdlc">
            <DataSources>
                <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="odsAdmission" Name="DSAdmission" />
                <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="odsInitialService" Name="DSInitialService" />
            </DataSources>
        </LocalReport>
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>

    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsAdmission" runat="server" 
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
        SelectMethod="SelectAdmissionForReport" 
        TypeName="PrecisionCareBLL.AdmissionBLL.AdmissionLogic">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="admissionId" QueryStringField="Id" 
                Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>  

    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsInitialService" runat="server" 
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
        SelectMethod="SelectAdmissionForReport" 
        TypeName="PrecisionCareBLL.AdmissionBLL.AdmissionLogic">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="admissionId" QueryStringField="Id" 
                Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Still it worked fine and project successfully built.
But when I added another DataSet in RDLC file, I am getting these errors:

```
Error   27  The rectangle ‘rectAdmission’ and the rectangle ‘rectServicePlanDue’ overlap. Overlapping report items are not supported in all renderers.
```

And lots of such errors.
Why it was working fine previously and what happened now?
When I remove newly added dataset from RDLC file, it again works fine.

Please anyone can tell me the reason behind that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the rdlc file.. Go to Report menu ->Data sources. Select the datasource which you newly added and press the Remove button then give Ok.